# Storing web-development libraries locally and update them whenever you are connected to internet

Tags: windows, javascript, ruby

I'm learning things on the web and pretty much have developed several websites. Internet in our country is a bit poor and slow so developing using ruby or node js is pretty much a pain in the ass because sometimes or most of the time you need the internet to be able to install module/gem dependencies.

Is there a way so that I can store selected libraries locally and access them import them whenever I need them?

In my text editor I am able to fetch things using [Fetch](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/introducing-nettuts-fetch/) and it was superb, you are able to fetch files and packages, but you need the internet, one way I tried is to download all libraries such as jquery, underscore and store them in a folder in my drive, create a nodejs server and serve static files. I can then add the local address to the json file and start the server, by then I am able to do my thing?

Is there such an app that lets me download things automatically whenever I get online?